# Laravel sending raw request body

Tags: json, laravel

I am trying to send an API request to the endpoint, and it is successful via Postman raw JSON, Now I am implementing the same in Laravel with HTTP facade.

Below is a POSTMAN screenshot with the successful response from the endpoint.

[image]

Now in Laravel I am struggling to send request, I tried below code, but yes, it shows unexpected `{`

```
        $response = Http::withBody(jData={"apkversion": "1.0.0",
            "uid": "dsfee3",
            "pwd": "deeddee",
            "factor2": "680208",
            "vc":"eefsdf",
            "appkey":"wefdsesdfd334",
            "imei": "abc1234",
            "source": "API"
            })->post('https://api.shoonya.com/NorenWClientTP/QuickAuth');
```

How can I send a request with given parameters as raw JSON?

Comment: that is not valid PHP

Answer (score 0):

When using the `Http::withBody()` you need to provide the body as a `string` and specify the content type. However, for sending JSON data, it's more common  to use the `Http::post()` with `->body()` or `->json()` to automatically handle the JSON encoding and set the appropriate headers.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

$response = Http::withHeaders([
      'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    ])
    ->post('https://api.shoonya.com/NorenWClientTP/QuickAuth', [
       "jData" => [
          "apkversion" => "1.0.0",
          "uid" => "dsfee3",
          "pwd" => "deeddee",
          "factor2" => "680208",
          "vc" => "eefsdf",
          "appkey" => "wefdsesdfd334",
          "imei" => "abc1234",
          "source" => "API",
       ]
   ]);
```

Comment: but my endpoint must see ```jData```, else it shows error with ```jData``` is missing, If you see in POSTMAN screenshot, i must send exact syntax which include jData as object.

Comment: just add `jData` key as it is not present in your code. Also, your original code is not a valid PHP and more like python (due to the `{dict}` thing)

Answer (score 0):

It was resolved by using below code...

```
 $response = Http::withBody("jData=".json_encode([
        "apkversion" => "1.0.0",
        "uid" => "dsfee3",
        "pwd" => "deeddee",
        "factor2" => "680208",
        "vc" => "eefsdf",
        "appkey" => "wefdsesdfd334",
        "imei" => "abc1234",
        "source" =>  "API"
    ])->post('https://api.shoonya.com/NorenWClientTP/QuickAuth');
```